# 'Lumpable states' analysis for a large transition matrix

Tags: r, markov-process, transition-matrix

I have a large transition matrix, whereby I calculate n-step state distribution results for `n=1..10`, and then merge states of interest for each `n` for presentation clarity. This is fine, but it doesn't produce much insight into the rather cumbersome transition matrix.

Therefore, my question is about available software tools, perhaps using `R`, for exploring and analysing the transition matrix for 'lumpable states', as described in Section 2.17 of Minh (see ref below), but also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpability. The possibility of lumpable approximations might also be interesting (notwithstanding Markov property issues), again for exploratory purposes.

I have been using `markovchain` in `R`. An enquiry to the package author indicates that this would have to be a new feature.

If my R coding was stronger I might attempt this, but I'd value any suggestions.

*Reference:*
Minh, D.L. (Paul), 2001. Applied Probability Models, Duxbury. 
Available at: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Probability-Models-Paul-Minh/dp/053438157X

Comment: So what is your question, explicitly? Given a Markov chain, finding the partition that shrinks it into a smaller state space chain?

Comment: It would relatively straightforward to iterate through all possible partitions and check that a transition matrix is lump able with that partition. But that would be a question for stackoverflow, and you probably want to throw up a specific trans-mat

Comment: My question is, explicitly, how can I do this (e.g. what software tools)? And implicitly, should I do this? Does this question therefore fit with this forum?